# Php artisan migrate TrustProxies not found

Tags: php, laravel, fatal-error

I am new to PHP Laravel, and I'm getting started on building a site using the tutorials. The site was working fine, and then I created a database I ran `php artisan migrate` which created the built in tables defined in the migration directory. Now, when I  run `php artisan serve` I get `FatalErrorException Class 'Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies not found in TrustProxies.php (line 9)` What is going on, and how can I fix this error?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?  Are you using Homestead/Valet?

Comment: 5.4.36 and Homestead

Comment: Have you tried disabling the dependency and then rerunning `composer install`?

Comment: The dependencies are listed in Composer.json if I am correct? I couldn't find the dependency there

Comment: There is no `TrustProxies` middleware in 5.4 by default, that comes with 5.5 ... if you are actually on 5.4 you will have to get some software   ... it would be wise to not follow any tutorials that are not for the version of Laravel you are using